# Validating entire string as json using jackson

Tags: java, scala, jackson

I'm using the following code to parse json

```
new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonStr)
```

But it parses the following string successfully since it looks like it stops processing once it finds a valid tree, even though the string in its entirety is not a valid json.

```
{
  "name": "test",
},
  "field": "c"
}
```

Is there a way to make it consider the entire string or stream passed? I couldn't find an appropriate option in `DeserializationFeature`.

Note that the solution doesn't have to involve jackson. If there's a simpler way to do that in java or scala, that'll suffice too.

Answer (score 1):

With Jackson you can use Streaming API, `JsonParser`, to read a json like and validate like follows:

```
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
jsonFactory.enable(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION);
try (JsonParser parser = jsonFactory.createParser(invalidJson)) {
    while (!parser.isClosed()) {
        parser.nextToken();
    }
}
```

For example, if there is json string of

```
{ 
  "name": "test"
},
  "field": "c"
}
```

A `JsonParseException` will be thrown as follows:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character
>   (',' (code 44)): expected a valid value (number, String, array,
>   object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:     { 
>         "name": "test"
>       },
>         "field": "c"
>       }; line: 3, column: 3]

`jsonFactory.enable(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION)` is to  explicitly check that no duplicate JSON Object field names are encountered.  If enabled, parser will check all names within context and report duplicates by throwing a `JsonParseException`

Answer (score -2):

According to : http://jsonlint.com/

The JSON you are using is not valid. You might want to correct it to get rid of the Exception :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "field": "c"
}
```